# OK Cancel buttons in EditTextPreference Android

Tags: android, button, android-2.3-gingerbread, edittextpreference

In the new version of android, the best practice is to have CANCEL - OK button in this particular order. In older versions, the default order is OK - CANCEL.

I am developing an app for 2.3.3 and up. I have set all my buttons to be in the CANCEL - OK order. However, the EditTextPreference dialog for 2.3.3 phones will display the old format OK - CANCEL.

Is there a way to change this or will I have to create my own custom dialog for changing the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HoloEverywhere` [library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) and you will have Holo style for old devices also (including dialogs/ prefer `DialogFragments`).